# Calling UIAlertView on UITextField UIControlEventEditingDidBegin dismisses keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

I've noticed some very weird behavior. I would like to show a UIAlertView when a UITextField is selected:

```
[self.addressTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(addressTextFieldSelected) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

The method that is being called is:

```
- (void)addressTextFieldSelected {

    if (!geoPoint) {

        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];

    }

}
```

When the textField is touched, the keyboard does start to slide up. However, as the alertView appears, the keyboard dismisses. After selecting 'OK' and dismissing the alertView the textfield's keyboard slides up.

**Edit**

With the help of others I've created this work around, although I'm a bit dissatisfied that the keyboard disappears in the first place.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField.tag == 2) {

        if (!geoPoint && !justShowedGeoPointAlert) {

            showingGeoPointAlert = YES;

            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Make sure to geotag this address." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];

            return NO;

        } else {

            justShowedGeoPointAlert = NO;

        }

    }

    return YES;

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (showingGeoPointAlert) {

        justShowedGeoPointAlert = YES;
        showingGeoPointAlert = NO;
        [self.addressTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    }

}
```

Comment: So what do you want in your app? both keyboard & AlertView at the same time?

Comment: @BC_Dlium I would like either 1: the alertView appears and the keyboard doesn't slide up at all until the alertView is dismissed or 2: the keyboard appears as the alertView is launched and stays there. Right now with the keyboard sliding up and then vanishing it looks really glitchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the following delegate method of UITextField:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Show alert view in this method, and return NO in this method, keyboard will not be shown.

Then implement the following delegate method of UIAlertView:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

In this method, show the keyboard:

```
[self.addressTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: does not work as the alertview gets shown every time the textfield becomes first responder...

Comment: You can keep a boolean, and set it's value depending on your logic.
Then, in the "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" method, show or don't show and return NO/YES depending upon the value of that boolean.

Comment: ...without being able to handle multiple textfields.

Comment: to handle multiple text fields, UITextField's tag can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Move your code for `UIAlertView` to `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` and if you return `NO` keyboard will not appear

Comment: Thanks, this is part of the solution!

Answer (score 1):

try something like the following:

```
@interface ViewController () <UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UITextField *selectedTextField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.selectedTextField) {
        self.selectedTextField = nil;
        return YES;
    }

    self.selectedTextField = textField;

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Text" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    return NO;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [self.selectedTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works equally well to Aneeq's but he posted first so I gave him the answer :P